# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo When Activity Is Not Present

Tags: android

So I had created an activity called `BagActivity` and it's adapter etc. and have since deleted it as it was no longer required. I clean built the project, uninstalled apk from test devices and yet, I get the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                  Process: in.ddas.pretense, PID: 11858
                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{in.ddas.pretense/in.ddas.pretense.BagActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                      at in.ddas.pretense.BagActivity.onCreate(BagActivity.java:28)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

What seems to be the problem?
Thanks.

*EDIT*: If I run this app in a different test device this error doesn't show! Why show it for 1 device?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you haven't deleted all BugActivity staff.

You have an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
           at in.ddas.pretense.BagActivity.onCreate(BagActivity.java:28)
```

It caused second exception. So it says that you try to work with null RecyclerView object in onCreate method of BagActivity. You may delete layout of BagActivity without deleting activity class.

Comment: I have and if I run this app in a different device this error doesn't show!

Comment: Nexus 6 The Motorola One?